# I failed to install Magisk and now I can't get out of TWRP

Tags: twrp, boot-loop, magisk

I have a Xiaomi redmi note 8, which runs on MIUI-11,
I've recently unlocked my phone with MiUnlock, the official program of xiaomi to unlock (root) your phone.
I've stumbled across a few hickupps, but eventually I got here, I can't get further though...
I installed TWRP using the ADB terminal, wiped the cache, flashed a zip that disables force encryption treble and after that, I installed Magisk (I did this all with the compatible versions for xiaomi redmi note 8). Normally, I should've been able to just reboot to the system, but TWRP just comes back.
When I reboot, I first see: Redmi by Xiaomi (screen 1)
Then: Redmi Note 8 by Xiaomi powered by android (screen 2), this takes longer than it normally should,
after that I see screen 1 again, and then again screen 2, whereafter I get the splashscreen from TWRP and it boots in recovery again...

I've already tried clearing the cache, enabling "System" in mount, tried to write this code in the advanced --> terminal option:
`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/misc bs=256 count=1 conv=notrunc`
Nothing helped me, one other weird thing that scares me is that, when I watch my folders with file explorer from windows, everything has gotten a random string as name... You can see it in my attachment.
[image: internal storage of xiaomi redmi note 8]

I would be soo grateful if someone could help me out.
Thanks for being awesome!

Comment: Is it an A/B device? Possibly you have flashed TWRP to boot partition.

Comment: the force encryption disabler did break fileencryption. do a factory reset to remove encryption completely and stay unencrypted. or restore/repair your fstab to bring encryption back to working state

Comment: @IrfanLatif What do you mean with A/B device? I've looked it up and it has something to do with how updates are installed, but I don't really get it.
I've just used the adb commands:
```adb devices -->
fastboot recovery twrp.img -->
fastboot boot twrp.img``` 
So I don't know where it normally gets flashed

Comment: @alecxs Do you mean within TWRP itself? Or with mi flash or another desktop program?

Comment: If I need to use wipe, which partitions should I wipe? System too? or only ART cache, Data, Internal Storage and Cache?

Comment: make sure you **format** (that is different from normal *wipe*) *TWRP -> Wipe -> Format Data -> (type:) "yes"* (if that fails, reboot and try again)

Comment: @alecxs , thanks, I did a format, but it removed my entire software, including my previous MIUI, got wiped. I've managed to fix this using Xiaomi adb/fastboot tools. Right now, I am back on MIUI, and still trying to get LineageOS.

Comment: when your device uses (FBE) file based encryption force encryption disabler will break it again. i recommend to preserve force encryption and disable dm-verity only. for LineageOS do not wipe *vendor* only *system*

Comment: @alecxs Okay, thanks, I stumbled on another Issue, my adb doesn't recognise my phone anymore, when I type ```adb devices``` I get ```List of devices attached``` and then an empty space where I had a number before, so I can't boot into twrp anymore :((

Comment: Volume Down + Power = fastboot, Volume Up + Power = recovery

Comment: Yes, but TWRP is gone from the moment you reboot with your phone, so I need to use adb to flash TWRP again, and atm, that isn't possible because adb doesn't recognise my phone

Comment: I managed to break it again, I got into TWRP, managed to install magisk, tried to install LineageOS, and now my phone loops in the "Redmi by xiaomi" screen, it just goes on, 2 seconds later, goes off, and on again, But I can still boot into TWRP. I used  LineageOS 17.1 from this link: [link](https://www.getdroidtips.com/lineage-os-17-1-redmi-note-8/)

Comment: It's encryption issue. restore original */vendor/etc/fstab.qcom*

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the data download the stock fastboot rom for your device and flash it.

From your comments above it looks like you've already wiped your data.

So I would suggest that you download the stock fastboot rom. Do a clean all flash. Don't do the clean all and lock flash, as it will lock your phone.

Once it's finished, you can flash twrp but don't try to disable file based encryption and then try flashing whatever other rom you were trying